# .xib file name is changed into ~iphone.nib while creating bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am creating the framework, in that i have xib, images etc.. in frame work i am creating custom `tableViewCell` called `SampleTableviewCell.xib`. While this file is build into Bundle the name of the xib file is converted into `SampleTableviewCell~iphone.nib`. Because of this i am getting crash while loading this xib file in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
SampleTableviewCell *cell = (SampleTableviewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SampleTableviewCell"];
```

My crash is,

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ACEB5838-EC42-416F-95AA-4CE5932D5849/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B20C8F8B-5E09-4D84-960C-614185E955DE/myapp.app/MySDK.bundle> (not yet loaded)' with name 'SampleTableviewCell''
```

I dont know why it is hapening. Anyone please help me to fix this issue.Actually i dont want to have ~iphone in bundle.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long struggle i found the solution,

In my xcode 7 beta 4 , `changed the Deployment target of bundle from 6.0 to 8.0`

This was protect me from creating nib file post fixed with ~iphone .

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SampleTableviewCell~iphone" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:self.cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SampleTableviewCell"];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually i found this already. But i want the nib name should be as my xib name..

Comment: it is a bad practice to add the device specifier to the `xib`'s name during loading; and it is much worse to recommend such thing.